# Ok to return const references/pointers to std::vectors across dll boundaries?

Tags: c++, templates, dll, std

I have business logic in a separate dll, and to be able to export a class from this dll for use by for example GUI classes, I have been told not to pass any std template objects like std::vector across the dll interface boundary. However, I am allowed to pass references and pointers to template type objects.

When would it be ok to pass a reference or a pointer to a std::vector (filled with pointers if that makes a difference) to code outside of the business logic/across the dll boundary (as a return value from getters). Example:

```
const std::vector<int*>& getNumbers();
const std::vector<int*>* getNumbers();
```

Can I always to this? What are the implications of the two alternatives compared to just passing by value?

Or should I avoid passing the std::vector altogether and what would be the alternatives in that case?

EDIT: I know passing of objects across dll boundaries is problematic and you have to know which compiler is used etc. I am wondering if returning const references and pointers can be a workaround in anyway, since I was told that it is, and if this is good practice.

Comment: Be *very* careful about passing non-builtin types and *especially* non-POD user-defined types across library boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason that justifies "not to pass any std template objects like std::vector across the dll interface boundary" will apply equally to passing pointers and references to std::vector.

When the code across the boundary dereferences the pointer, it will run into the same issue.

So, no.

Comment: the thing I don't understand is, that when I export a class containing the member: std::vector<int*> myvector I get a warning:

 "MyClass::myvector": class "std::vector<int *,std::allocator<_Ty>>" erfordert eine DLL-Schnittstelle, die von Clients von class "MyClass" verwendet wird" (German, meaning the member needs a DLL-interface).

If I change to std::vector<int*>& myvector there is no warning any more...

I guess that is at least why people here think that changing to reference solves the problem...

Comment: Well, technically it is OK to pass a pointer if the other side is never going to dereference it. As such, the compiler cannot warn. But, in practice, you'd be hard-pressed to find a case where you pass pointers and the other side only uses the pointer values, without ever dereferencing them.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand much better what is going on here... and I will definitely want to dereference my pointers on the other side

Comment: @JeffreysupportsMonica adding to that, see 'opaque pointer' (there is a good article on wiki),